# jQuery addClass based on browser version

Tags: jquery, browser

Wondering if this works for anybody, I can't get the addClass to work but if I change it to an alert, it works.

```
var bro = $.browser;
      if (bro.msie && bro.version.slice(0, 7) == "7.0") {
        $('#wrap').addClass('ie7');
      }
```

Comment: Are you 100000% sure the `wrap` element exists? Are you sure the addClass isn't working, did you check using a DOM inspector?

Comment: `$.browser` is deprecated, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Use conditional comments. http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: Why `slice(0,7)` if you're looking for a 3 char string?

Comment: Couple of things to check. Are you sure the wrap element is in the DOM? Could there possibly be two wrap elements in the DOM? Is the wrap element spelled incorrectly? Is the wrap element a class instead of an id? If the wrap element is dynamically being generated, is it actually making it to the DOM? Just a couple of suggestions.

Comment: @jfriend00 not really sure how the slice works, can I leave that off?

Comment: @SLaks normally I would use conditional comments but I don't have access to the head section of the template. It's locked down in the cms I'm stuck with.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. For some reason the jQuery generated class was not showing up when I used "View Source" in IE, it was there when I looked for it with Developer Tools.

Comment: View source doesn't show dynamic modifications.  It only shows the raw HTML delivered by the server (before any modifications).  You need to use a DOM inspector to see the modified DOM.  Use the debugger built into Chrome, IE or Firebug add-on for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, you are determining that the class was not added by using View/Source.  But, View/Source only shows the raw HTML delivered by the server BEFORE any dynamic modifications.

To see dynamic DOM modifications, you need to use a DOM inspector to see the modified DOM. Use the debugger built into Chrome, IE, Safari or Opera or the Firebug add-on for Firefox.

You can also use breakpoints or `console.log()` statements to verify what your code is or isn't actually doing.